# Not able to ping to ESXi6 from centos vm

Tags: virtual-machine, esxi

I am new to esxi.I have installed centos vm on esxi.esxi is connected to network.I have set the static ip to centos.Problem is when i try to ping esxi from the guest vm, its not pinging.I tried google it but i didnt get the info about ip configuration of guestvm(cent os).what should be the proper configuration to connect it to the network

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe you configuration and task more detailed? 
In general, after ESXi install in Configuration -> Networking you'll see Standard Switch with vmkernel port "Management network" with ESXi IP and portgroup "Vm Network". If you have no VLANs and one subnet, you need to set VLAN ID on both vmkernel and portgroup to "None (0)", and made same subnet/gateway settings on vmkernel and inside guest. At last, you need to set in VM Settings - Hardware -> Network Adapter 1 -> Network Label to "Vm Network". 
It's difficult to advise more without info.